# Prove that $C_H(K) = N_H(K)$ for $G=H \rtimes_{\phi} K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, semidirect-product

Let $H,K$ be group where $\phi: K \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is a homomorphism. Also, let $G=H \rtimes_{\phi} K$.

Show that $C_H(K) = N_H(K)$

Proof:
Let $h\in N_H(K)=\{h\in H: hKh^{-1}=K\}$.  Then for any $k\in K$, $\exists \; k' \in K$ where $hkh^{-1}=k'$.  Let $\pi_{k'}(h)$ be an action by left conjugation that affords $\phi$.  Then $\pi_{k'}(h)=k'hk'^{-1}=(hkh^{-1})h(hkh^{-1})^{-1}=hkh^{-1}hhk^{-1}h^{-1}=(hk)h(hk)^{-1}$.  Thus $hk=k'$ and since $H\cap K=1$, then $h=1$.  Thus $N_H(K)=1$ and $C_H(K)=1$ (as it is a subgroup of $N$).

Is this proof correct?  Huge Thanks goes out to anyone who helps me out here!

Comment: Your conclusion is too strong.  What if $G$ is abelian?  Both the centralizer and the normalizer would be the entire group.

Comment: $G$ can be abelian, but the subgroups of $G$ can still be disjoint.  That being said, $N_H(K)$ isnt the same thing as $N_G(K)$.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Whoops.  I was looking at normalizers in the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the notation in $\phi_k = \phi(k) \in \operatorname{Aut} H$, the multiplication is given by
$$
(h_1, k_1) (h_2, k_2) = (h_1\, \phi_{k_1}(h_2), k_1 k_2).
$$
You have probably already done the calculations to show that $H$ and $K$ embed in $G = H \rtimes_\phi K$ as
$$
\{ (h, 1) \mid h \in H \} \quad \text{and} \quad \{ (1, k) \mid k \in K \}.
$$
Also, you've likely worked out that
$$
(h, k)^{-1} = ( \phi_{k^{-1}}(h^{-1}), k^{-1}).
$$
Now choose $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ and conjugate in $G$:
$$
(h, 1) (1, k) (h, 1)^{-1} = (h, k) (h^{-1}, 1) = (h \phi_k(h^{-1}), k).
$$
If $h \in N_H(K)$, then $(h \phi_k(h^{-1}), k) = (1, k')$ for some $k' \in K$.  This implies that $k' = k$, so $h \in C_H(K)$.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd not considered writing the elements of the groups (separately) in cross product form (though i probably should have :/).  That's really informative!  Btw, you should get a big up-vote... though I don't quite have the rep yet.

Comment: How proof this result with Dedekind's Law?